# Как зациклить добавление класса 'active' в карусели

Tags: jquery

У меня есть карусель и dots-навигация, для переключения которой я использую этот скрипт:

```js
$('.owl-dot').click(function() {
  var $current = $('.owl-dot.active');
  $current.removeClass('active');
  $current.next('.owl-dot').addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider-dots">
  <div class="owl-dot active">active</div>
  <div class="owl-dot">active</div>
  <div class="owl-dot">active</div>
</div>
```

Но когда доходит до конца, то последний `.owl-dot` перестает быть активным. Как это исправить, зациклив добавление класса?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.owl-dot').click(function() {
  $('.owl-dot').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider-dots">
  <div class="owl-dot active">active</div>
  <div class="owl-dot">active</div>
  <div class="owl-dot">active</div>
</div>
```

Comment: это не работает, класс 'аctive' добавляется к текущему элементу и сразу же удаляется. А нужно чтобы он добавлялся только к выбраному, при клике на другой элемент  - удалялся у предыдущего и и добавился к тому, на который кликнули. Ваш вариант не тот.

Comment: Это так и работает...  Если кто-то сделает лучше, я буду рад увидеть и научиться новому методу....