# Зациклить слайдер Jquery

Tags: html, css, jquery, веб-программирование

имеется код

```js
 $(document).on("click", "a.slider__control_right", function(e) {
   var selectedItem = $('#slider').find('.slider__item--dis');

   selectedItem.removeClass('slider__item--dis');
   selectedItem.next().addClass('slider__item--dis');

});
```

```html
<div class="slider__wrapper" id="slider">
   <div class="slider__item slider__item--dis">
   </div>
   <div class="slider__item">
   </div>
   <div class="slider__item">
   </div>
   <div class="slider__item">
   </div>
</div>
```

Подобный вопрос представлен [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/787834/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0-active-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8?rq=1), не пойму как организовать зацикливание, т.е. чтобы по прохождении всех элементов активный класс возвращался к первому элементу массива

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $(document).on("click", "a.slider__control_right", function(e) {
   var selectedItem = $('#slider').find('.slider__item--dis');

   selectedItem.removeClass('slider__item--dis');
   selectedItem.next().addClass('slider__item--dis');

   if ($('#slider .slider__item--dis').length == 0)
     $('#slider .slider__item').eq(0).addClass('slider__item--dis');
});
```